# Is settled court cases on topic for this site?

Tags: discussion

Say a person is accused of murder.

Say we doubt he really did it.

Is that on topic?

It's notable. Definitely.

It's answerable based on evidence.

So it seems like it's a model question. It's on topic. Reasonable numbers of people is

Some answers here says it's on topic.

Not quite clear

[Are allegations of infamous crimes off topic for Skeptics?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/are-allegations-of-infamous-crimes-off-topic-for-skeptics)

Sample:

[Did Antasari Commit the Murder?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/42907/did-antasari-commit-the-murder?noredirect=1#comment189838_42907)

Note: For some reason I feel it's off topic. However, I can't really figure out how. For some reason also, I feel asking if https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreyfus_affair is a traitor is on topic. I just can't really point out why. Just a hunch.

Comment: You are asking the same question, if you feel the answers are unclear, let's move the discussion over there.

Comment: @user4951 The difference here is that this was a **court case**, not just some random claim that people on Facebook or a rambling media personality threw about. This is a claim that has been accepted by a **court of law**, after examining evidence that is **not** publicly to us here att Skeptics SE, and where the accuser has to prove their claim. So **no**, this is not a suitable claim to be examined by us here at Skeptics SE. And I say again: it seems to me that you are not approaching this as a skeptic but as someone that **wants to disbelieve the claim**.

Comment: There's another big problem with your question as well.  You say "Say a person is accused of murder."  The situation that you are trying to ask about wasn't if a person was accused of murder, he was TRIED and CONVICTED.  An answer in the affirmative would essentially re-state the trial verdict.  I'm not even sure what an answer in the negative would look like.

Comment: Antasari is convicted by a court with very dubious integrity. Judges routinely accept bribes or perceived as doing so (lawyers often claim that judges as bribes to con more money from his client). That is Indonesia's court. Also evidences and the whole court proceeding is public. Somewhere. Judges decisions are public like in US. In fact, we have more evidences than judges because we do not suppress evidences

Comment: That duplicate question have answers that say that yes, it's on topic on those sites. My question is closed. It's notable. It's dubious (some think yes some think no). It's answerable

Comment: An answer in the negative would point out that the court is bribed or not neutral like Dreyfus affair.

Comment: Vote for reopen. In Antasari case, as far as I know, I have never seen any strong or clear proof that Antasari committed the murder. Someone else committed the murder and that someone claim Antasari did it. May be I do not know enough evidences. May be the court is just being a crook. I want to know that.